# Creating a very basic calculator in C++

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm extremely new to C++, I was following a tutorial and wanted to go a bit off what the course said, I attempted to make a basic calculator that instead of just being able to add could subtract, divide and multiply but it still seems to only be able to add, why is this?

```
  int num1, num2;
  double sum;
  int addType;
  cout << "Type a number: ";
  cin >> num1;
  cout << "Type a second number: ";
  cin >> num2;
  cout << "Do you want to 1. add, 2. subtract, 3. divide or 4. multiply: ";
  cin >> addType;
  if (int addType = 1) {
    sum = num1 + num2;
  }
  else if (int addType = 2) {
    sum = num1 - num2;
  }

  else if (int addType = 3) {
    sum = num1 / num2;
  }
  else if (int addType = 4) {
    sum = num1 * num2;
  }
  
  cout << "Your total is: " << sum;
  
}
```

Comment: `int addType = x` --> `addType == x`. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of improvising from tutorials.

Comment: `if (int addType = 1) {` creates a new variable `addType` which shadows  and sets its value to 1. Then tests if it is not zero and executes the `sum = num1 - num2;` because 1 is not 0.

Comment: If you can't get your hands on a book, try working through these tutorials first :  https://www.learncpp.com/ (books can be outdated, or focus more on teaching about datastructures using C++ then teaching about good programming using C++ )

Comment: don't ignore compiler warnings https://godbolt.org/z/K4TK5z96e.

Comment: *I was following a tutorial and wanted to go a bit off what the course said* -- Don't do this if you're a beginner in C++.  If you want to go "off course", then the new course better be following another good C++ tutorial.  As you can see, you can write C++ that has valid syntax, but is still junk and does something totally different than what you expect.

Comment: i'm of the opinion doing anything is acceptable.  Write your own code or follow a tutorial is doing.  Doing is good.  Focus on learning and enjoying now.  You can worry about mastery later.  Best of luck to you on your endeavors @Aviation6!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating new variable in if condition part, update condition part to check if it is equal to something with `addType == x`

```cpp
int num1, num2;
 double sum;
 int addType;
 cout << "Type a number: ";
 cin >> num1;
 cout << "Type a second number: ";
 cin >> num2;
 cout << "Do you want to 1. add, 2. subtract, 3. divide or 4. multiply: ";
 cin >> addType;
 if (addType == 1) {
   sum = num1 + num2;
 }
 else if (addType == 2) {
   sum = num1 - num2;
 }

 else if (addType == 3) {
   sum = num1 / num2;
 }
 else if (addType == 4) {
   sum = num1 * num2;
 }
 
 cout << "Your total is: " << sum;
 
}
```

Comment: So == is standard formatting, cheers

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "standard formatting". A single `=` _assigns_ the value on the right hand side (rhs) to the variable on the left hand side (lhs): `sum = num1 + num2`. A double `==` _compares_ the rhs and the lhs: `if(num2 == 0) { ... }`. They are two completely different operators (that happen to look similar) regardless of "formatting".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking equality, your `if` conditions are initialising the `addType` var. It should be:

```
if (addType == 1)
```

`=` means to assign a value, which will set `addType` to the value of `1`, and then the `if` will always be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (int addType = 1)
```

means assign 1 to "addType", "addType" is alway 1, so condition alway is true.You will only ever be able to add.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(int addType = 1)
```

this is a expression which defines a variable named addType and assigns it's value to 1.
so it basically becomes

```
if(1)
```

which is true. so instead of this write:

```
if( addType ==1)
```